# How to get object of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext in Console application?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace ActivationContextSample
{
 public class Program : MarshalByRefObject
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ActivationContext ac = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext;
        ApplicationIdentity ai = ac.Identity;
        Console.WriteLine("Full name = " + ai.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Code base = " + ai.CodeBase);
        Console.Read();
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        Main(new string[] { });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

**Error: Unhandled Exception:**
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at ActivationContextSample.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000b] in <7d43242f5912432d822ac735ddb97f04>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at ActivationContextSample.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000b] in <7d43242f5912432d822ac735ddb97f04>:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating executable application and run it. In that case you will get the required object.

Comment: Let me check thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint you should be able to see that AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext is null.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).